# Convert a Seq["key1=val1"] to a Map[String, String] in Scala

Tags: scala, split, pattern-matching

I have the following Seq[String], with all strings with `=` delimiter.

```
keysVals = ["Country=France", "City=Paris"]
```

I would like to convert it into a Map[String, String], such as

```
result = Map("Country"->"France", "City"->"Paris")
```

How to do that, please?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Map(keysVals.map(keyVal => keyVal .split("=",2)(0))->keysVals .map(keyVal => keyVal .split("=",2)(1)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest way seems to be

```
data.map { case s"${k}=${v}" => k -> v }.toMap
```

using [`StringContext.s.unapplySeq`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/StringContext$s$.html) as in

```
val data = List("Country=France", "City=Paris")
println(data.map { case s"${k}=${v}" => k -> v }.toMap)
```

(thanks @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez).

---

Alternatively, with Regex pattern-matching:

```
val KeyValuePattern = "([^=]+)=([^=]+)".r
data.map { case KeyValuePattern(k, v) => k -> v }.toMap
```

---

With good old `String.split`:

```
data.map(str => str.split("=") match { case Array(k, v) => k -> v }).toMap
```

Comment: You can just `list.map { case s"${key}=${value}" => k -> v }-toMap`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks, added this as the first and preferred solution.