# Pattern match inline regex

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I know I can pattern match on regex with captures like this:

```
val re = """a(\d)""".r
"a5" match {
  case re(x) => println(x)
  case _ => println("Oops")
}

5
```

I wonder if it's possible to have this regex inline. For below code I get an error:

```
"a5" match {
  case """a(\d)""".r(x) => println(x)
  case _ => println("Oops")
}

case """a(\d)""".r(x) => println(x)
                ^
On line 2: error: '=>' expected but '.' found.
```

Comment: "For below code I get an error:" I think, you have your answer ...

Comment: Well, I might be just doing it wrong, no? I tried also `case ("""a(\d)""".r)(x)` and other variations. But maybe something else would work?

Comment: Does [this answer about `s`-template patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74789642/convert-a-seqkey1-val1-to-a-mapstring-string-in-scala/74789788#74789788) answer your question? I.e. `case s"a${x}" => println(x)`.

Comment: Compiling a regex is somewhat expensive, it is not really a good idea to inline it even if possible.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin - thanks, I didn't know about this one. Not full power of regex, but for simple cases works nice.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - yes, I'm aware. Sometimes it's just one pass though.

Comment: It won't: specification doesn't allow it: https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html - you can use: type matching, literals, or direct references to objects ("stable values") that implement `unapply` (you cannot construct them in `case` clause).

Answer (score 0):

A short (and probably ugly) way to make it looking like an inline invocation may be the following:

```
  """a(\d)""".r.unapplySeq("a5") match {
    case Some(x) => println(x.mkString)
    case _ => println("Oops")
  }
```

so, you can create the Regex instance and later you can directly invoke the `unapplySeq` instead of using pattern matching. `unapplySeq` returns an `Option[List[String]]`, so you can eventually work on the Option instance there.

Or you can make it even shorter, such as:

```
println("""a(\d)""".r.unapplySeq("a5").fold("Oops")(_.mkString))
```